# backbone routes – detecting browser back button press

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to find a way to detect when the user has pressed the back / forward button in their browser.

I am using backbone to handle routes, along with backbone to render my views.

The issue is I can not hook into this page change event from anywhere.

I tried putting a log in my initialize function for my views .. but it is not tripped when i use the back button.

I am really not sure how else to detect this page change.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use `Backbone.Router` and make sure that you don't forget about `Backbone.history.start()` when starting your application.

Some useful information can be found [here](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/) and [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone/)

Actually the second link is not an article, but a blog. And the guy who wrote it really seems to know a lot about the topic.

UPD: The idea is that backbone's router fire binded methods when your url changing. So you just should put your logic to this method and this way you will able to track that. Maybe it's non very automatic way, and it will take to write some code but I think it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I read it. The idea is that backbone's router fire binded methods when your url changing. So you just should put your logic to this method and this way you will able to track that. Maybe it's non very automatic way, and it will take to write some code but I think it should work.

Comment: @Ph0en1x You are correct that using Backbone's History object can provide a solution since it monitors the 'popstate' event which is fired when the back button is pressed when navigating within the site.  However, your answer does not make it clear that that's what you're saying nor how OP would resolve his problem using Backbone.History.

Comment: Funny, there is a lot of minuses for that answer. However answer itself intentionally correct even in the end of 2015. But looks like people don't want to read carefully and don't want to think. They just want to copy-paste snippet.

Comment: @Ph0en1x: I think the question is how to capture the actual "back/forward" event, not just when the URL changing. For example, if I am at a view /app, then I go to view app/about. If I call the method: router.navigate('/app', {trigger: true, replace: true}), how would you tell from `app` view whether user clicked "back" button or not? From my point of view, I would treat those two cases differently.

Comment: "Some useful information can be found here and here" - both links are dead unfortunately as of today @Ph0en1x

Answer (score 10):

You can bind a callback to Backbone `route` event:

```
    Backbone.history.on('route', function () {
        // Do your stuff here
    });
```

You can use `Backbone.history.getFragment()` to know were you are standing.

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis ) at the end of your snippet

Answer (score 3):

When the back button is pressed a **popstate** event is triggered.

I'm using this piece of code:

```
// listening for the browser's back button
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
    router.navigate(Backbone.history.getFragment(), { trigger: true, replace: true });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the `Backbone.Router` and overload the `route` and the `open` method. You have all page changings handled in those two methods. So just recopy them from the backbone file, and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously even GitHub does not know how to detect which button was pressed ;)
They use this code:

```
slideTo: function (a) {
      var b = this.pathFromURL(a),
         c = this.frameForPath(b),
         d = $("#slider .frame-center").attr("data-path") || "";
      c.is(".frame-center") || (d == "/" || b.split("/").length > d.split("/").length ?
        this.slideForwardTo(a) : this.slideBackTo(a))
}
```