# Browser Button not triggering routes in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am developing a web app using backbone, jQuery and BAAS of stackmob. I am running into an issue with browser buttons not triggering the backbone routes. Navigation proceeds smooth from one view to other when I use `router.navigate(url,{trigger:true});`. Below is how my routes are set up:

```
routes:{
    "":"home",
    ":query": "userProfile",
    ":query/:postsId": "postShow"
},
```

And from my view i m navigating as

```
router.navigate(userName+"/"+e.target.id, {trigger: true});
```

The navigation proceeds smoothly and i reach 3rd view of my app, However issue comes with the browser back button and forward button, as in route methods are never triggered for both.

Route call backs are

```
home:function(e) {
    console.log("Route 1");

},
userProfile:function(query){
    console.log(query);

},
postShow:function(query,postsId){
    console.log("Route 3");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use `Backbone.Router` and make sure that you don't forget
>   about `Backbone.history.start()` when starting your application.
>
> Some useful information can be found [here](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/) and [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone/)
>
> Actually the second link is not an article, but a blog. And the guy
>   who wrote it really seems to know a lot about the topic.
>
> from [backbone routes – detecting browser back button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235509/backbone-routes-detecting-browser-back-button-press?rq=1)

Comment: Already have this in my router.js :
 var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.pubSub = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
    Backbone.history.start({
     root:"/"
    });
  };

And have already followed the above articles but to no use.